# Tornado: not making async request

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I'm a newbie to [Tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado) and I'm trying to use it to make an async call as in the [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient):

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

def handle_response(response):
    """Handles response"""
    print 'here'
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_response)
```

When I run this program nothing is printed :(

The program just runs and exits.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I hope my answer is what you are looking for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start the IOLoop for asynchronous stuff to run. The last line of a tornado program is typically `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()`. You'd then call `IOLoop.current().stop()` in `handle_response`, assuming this one request is all you want to do.

Another way to start and stop the IOLoop for a single function is like this: `response = IOLoop.current().run_sync(functools.partial(http_client.fetch, url))` (and then you'd handle the response afterwards)

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm receiving this error: NameError: name 'tornado' is not defined

Comment: Regarding the second way, I'm looking for an async approach. I'm coming from node.js into Python - it seems like a very different way of thinking and coding.

Comment: Looks like this is needed: import tornado.ioloop

Comment: And what's weird is that every line of code after `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()` is completely ignored

Comment: It's not ignored, it just can't run until the ioloop is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please check are you running your code through python 3.4 ?

Next thing is please check print statement where there is no brackets.

As I have run your code with little changes and it worked.

```
>>> def handle_response(response):
...     if response.error:
...             print("error: {}".format(response.error))
...     else:
...             print(response.body)
...
>>> http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
>>> http_client.fetch("https://www.google.com",handle_response)
<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x03ADF570>
```